# Alternative to *= operator in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sybase

I have a Sybase SQL which is having following operator. *= 
I need to convert the sql to work with MySQL. But this operator gives me a an error there. What's the alternative way to use it in MySQL. 
This is part of the sql I'm getting the problem .

```
( dba.mstaccbalance.comp_code *= dba.trnglupdate.comp_code ) and  
         ( dba.mstaccbalance.mst_type *= dba.trnglupdate.mst_type ) and  
         ( dba.mstaccbalance.acc_code *= dba.trnglupdate.mst_code ) and  
            ( dba.mstaccbalance.lvl_gl_code *= dba.trnglupdate.lvl_gl_code )
```

Do I have to rewrite the SQL using left outer joins or is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

**`*=` is `LEFT JOIN` and `=*` is `RIGHT JOIN`.**

in sysbase you can query like this

```
select * from a, b where a.id *= b.id
```

and in MySQL you can write this

```
select * from a left outer join b on a.id = b.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **Yes**. The `=*` and `*=` are not complaint with current SQL standards.

MySQL doesn't support the `*=` operator, instead you should use `LEFT JOIN`. Your query is easy to migrate so far as doesn't have any where clause that is where the differences with a normal `JOIN` comes.